# Passing ref down to child in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an app, where I need to manage focus on the inputs and for that purpose I use React `ref`.

I have two inputs that I want to move into a separate component. Now they look like following:

```
<input
  onChange={this.handleChangeOne}
  ref={refOne => (this.refOne = refOne as HTMLInputElement)}
  type="text"
/>
<input
  onChange={this.handleChangeTwo}
  ref={refTwo => (this.refTwo = refTwo as HTMLInputElement)}
  type="text"
/>
```

I am having trouble to make the them work in a separate component while it involves passing down ref prop. I've tried something like this:

```
<InputBlock

          handleChangeOne={() => this.handleChangeOne}
          handleChangeTwo={() => this.handleChangeTwo}
          refOne=(refOne => (this.refOne = refOne as HTMLInputElement)}
          refTwo={refTwo => (this.refTwo = refTwo as HTMLInputElement)}
        />
```

And the components itself

```
class InputBlock extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input
          ref={refOne}
          onChange={handleChangeOne}
          type="text"
        />
        <input
          ref={refTwo}
          onChange={handleChangeTwo}
          type="text"
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default InputBlock;
```

For the sake of example I want `handleChangeOne` to focus on input two, and `handleChangeTwo` to focus on input one

Comment: You need to create the refs inside of your constructor of the class where they are being created. Check the documentation regarding the [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: As the above code for the not isolated inputs is working, I specifically need a way to control them from parent component. In terms of ref creation it works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what went wrong for you, but the following is working for me:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class OuterComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  refOne: null | HTMLInputElement = null;
  refTwo: null | HTMLInputElement = null;
  render() {
    return <InputBlock
      handleChangeOne={this.handleChangeOne}
      handleChangeTwo={this.handleChangeTwo}
      refOne={refOne => (this.refOne = refOne)}
      refTwo={refTwo => (this.refTwo = refTwo)}
    />;
  }

  handleChangeOne = () => {
    console.log("handleChangeOne", this.refOne, this.refTwo);
  }
  handleChangeTwo = () => {
    console.log("handleChangeTwo", this.refOne, this.refTwo);
  }
}

interface IProps {
  refOne: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
  refTwo: React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
  handleChangeOne: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
  handleChangeTwo: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}
class InputBlock extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input
          ref={this.props.refOne}
          onChange={this.props.handleChangeOne}
          type="text"
        />
        <input
          ref={this.props.refTwo}
          onChange={this.props.handleChangeTwo}
          type="text"
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<OuterComponent/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot, and tell you if it works!

Comment: So I've tried it, and it works for logging the output, but when I try to do something there like `public handleChangeOne = () => { this.refTwo.focus();};` it gives me `Object is possibly null error` If you know how to fix that, I would appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out by myself! For anyone who will have the same problem, just check inside your handlers for refs to be true and execute block on this check

Answer (score 0):

For Functional Component:

```
import React,{useRef} from 'react';

const ParentComp = () => {
    const parentDivRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    return(
        <ChildButtonComp ref={parentDivRef}>Click Me</ChildButtonComp>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { Ref, forwardRef,ReactNode } from "react";

const ChildButtonComp = forwardRef(
  (props: { children: ReactNode }, ref: Ref<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    return <button ref={ref}>{props.children}</button>;
  }
);
```