# How can I send ref to my custom TextInput component as a prop?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The custom TextInput component is illustrated below. I'm new to Typescript and have never tried to construct custom components like TextInput before; I intend to utilize this in all of my other components.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Pressable, KeyboardType } from "react-native";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { defaultStyle } from "./inputStyle";

interface Input {
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  secured?: boolean;
  inputStyle?: object;
  iconName: string;
  iconSize?: number;
  keyboardType?: KeyboardType;
  onTextChange?: (text: string) => void | undefined;
  visibleLeftIcon?: boolean;
  Error?: string;
  selectionColor?: string;
}

export default function Input(input: Input) {
  const [isSecured, setSecured] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);

  let _Error = input?.Error?.length !== undefined && input?.Error?.length !== 0;

  return (
    <View style={defaultStyle.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>{input.label}</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          defaultStyle.wrapper,
          isFocused && defaultStyle.info,
          _Error && defaultStyle.warning,
        ]}
      >
        {input.visibleLeftIcon && (
          <View style={defaultStyle.icon}>
            <Ionicons
              name={input.iconName}
              size={input.iconSize ? input.iconSize : 22}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        <TextInput
          placeholder={input.placeholder}
          onChangeText={(text) =>
            input?.onTextChange && input?.onTextChange(text)
          }
          keyboardType={input.keyboardType}
          secureTextEntry={input.secured && isSecured}
          style={[defaultStyle.input, input.inputStyle]}
          onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
          onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
          selectionColor={input.selectionColor}
        />
        {input.secured && (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => setSecured(!isSecured)}
            style={defaultStyle.icon}
          >
            <Ionicons
              name={isSecured ? "ios-eye-off-outline" : "ios-eye-outline"}
              size={input.iconSize ? input.iconSize : 22}
            />
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </View>
      {_Error && (
        <View>
          <Text style={[defaultStyle.warning]}>{input?.Error}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is how I use it; I'm not sure how I'm going to pass a reference to my custom component. I tried searching but got no results.

```
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Input from "../Component/Input";

export default function AuthLayout() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Input
        label="First Input"
        secured={false}
        keyboardType="decimal-pad"
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        iconName="ios-person-circle-outline"
        visibleLeftIcon={true}
        selectionColor="black"
      />
      <Input
        label="Second Input"
        secured={true}
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        iconName="ios-person-circle-outline"
        keyboardType="default"
        placeholder="wambamram"
        visibleLeftIcon={true}
        selectionColor="red"
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417591

Comment: forwardRef or pass a prop to input named other than "ref"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the gist of the answer from this link [stackoverflow.com/a/52417591](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417591), but it was still difficult for me to understand because I had never used a class component before, but I found the solution, and I hope this helps someone else.

What I did was add additional params that accepts a useRef() hook and a callback.
I named it:

> onRef and onSubmitRef

```js
import React, { useState, RefObject } from "react"; // new import RefObject
import { View, Text, TextInput, Pressable, KeyboardType } from "react-native";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { defaultStyle } from "./inputStyle";

interface Input {
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  secured?: boolean;
  inputStyle?: object;
  iconName: string;
  iconSize?: number;
  keyboardType?: KeyboardType;
  onTextChange?: (text: string) => void | undefined;
  visibleLeftIcon?: boolean;
  Error?: string;
  selectionColor?: string;
  onRef?: RefObject<TextInput> | null | undefined; // props that accepts ref hook
  onSubmitRef?: () => void | undefined; // a callback that runs when TextInput submit
}

export default function Input(input: Input) {
  const [isSecured, setSecured] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);

  let _Error = input?.Error?.length !== undefined && input?.Error?.length !== 0;

  return (
    <View style={defaultStyle.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>{input.label}</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={[
          defaultStyle.wrapper,
          isFocused && defaultStyle.info,
          _Error && defaultStyle.warning,
        ]}
      >
        {input.visibleLeftIcon && (
          <View style={defaultStyle.icon}>
            <Ionicons
              name={input.iconName}
              size={input.iconSize ? input.iconSize : 22}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        <TextInput
          placeholder={input.placeholder}
          onChangeText={(text) =>
            input?.onTextChange && input?.onTextChange(text)
          }
          keyboardType={input.keyboardType}
          secureTextEntry={input.secured && isSecured}
          style={[defaultStyle.input, input.inputStyle]}
          onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
          onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
          selectionColor={input.selectionColor}
          ref={input?.onRef} // add the props onRef
          onSubmitEditing={() => input?.onSubmitRef && input?.onSubmitRef()} // a callback that runs when TextInput submit
        />
        {input.secured && (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => setSecured(!isSecured)}
            style={defaultStyle.icon}
          >
            <Ionicons
              name={isSecured ? "ios-eye-off-outline" : "ios-eye-outline"}
              size={input.iconSize ? input.iconSize : 22}
            />
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </View>
      {_Error && (
        <View>
          <Text style={[defaultStyle.warning]}>{input?.Error}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

```js
import React, { useRef, RefObject } from "react";
import { ScrollView, TextInput } from "react-native";
import Input from "../Component/Input";

export default function AuthLayout() {
  let currentRefOne: RefObject<TextInput> | null | undefined = useRef(null);
  let currentRefTwo: RefObject<TextInput> | null | undefined = useRef(null);

  const HandleFocusOne = () => {
    currentRefTwo?.current?.focus();
  };

  const HandleFocusTwo = () => {
    currentRefOne?.current?.focus();
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Input
        label="First Input"
        secured={false}
        keyboardType="decimal-pad"
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        iconName="ios-person-circle-outline"
        visibleLeftIcon={true}
        selectionColor="black"
        onRef={currentRefOne}
        onSubmitRef={() => HandleFocusOne()}
      />
      <Input
        onRef={currentRefTwo}
        onSubmitRef={() => HandleFocusTwo()}
        label="Second Input"
        secured={true}
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        iconName="ios-person-circle-outline"
        keyboardType="default"
        placeholder="wambamram"
        visibleLeftIcon={true}
        selectionColor="red"
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```